# Creating/allocating an array of p_threads

Tags: c, arrays, multithreading, struct, pthreads

I am learning about threads in C.

I am trying to allocate an array of p_thread structs so that they can all run some function and then join them together.

So my steps were:
1. create an pointer to an array of pthread structs (of varying size that user inputs)
2. Allocate the array of pthread structs 
3. Create a pthread for every array position

My code:

```
pthread_t * pthreadArray[userInputSize];
pthreadArray = malloc ((sizeof(pthread_t)) * userInputSize);
```

but I get an error:

```
incompatible types when assigning to type 'pthread_t *[(size type)(userInputSize)]' from type 'void *'
```

Can anyone clarify?

Comment: `pthread_t * pthreadArray[userInputSize];` --> `pthread_t * pthreadArray;`

Answer (score 0):

The line `pthread_t * pthreadArray[userInputSize];` is allocating an array of `pthread` pointers of size `userInputSize`. The second line is attempting to overwrite it with newly allocated pointer, which is not your intention. So you should just remove the  `[]` part from the first line. In addition there is some wrong parentheses in the second line. Fix it like this:

```
pthread_t * pthreadArray;
pthreadArray = malloc (sizeof(pthread_t) * userInputSize);
```

Comment: I know p_threadcreate returns 0 if no error, so how can I initialize each index of an array to a thread in hopes to join them later if it just returns 0 and not the thread or thread id?

Answer (score 0):

```
pthread_t * pthreadArray[userInputSize];
```

This declares an array of `pthread_t*` with length `userInputSize`. Which is probably not at all what you want. Not least because `userInputSize` is not known at compile time and so this would be a variable length array (VLA).

Surely you want to do this:

```
pthread_t *pthreadArray = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t) * userInputSize);
```

That makes `pthreadArray` be of type `pthread_t*`, and initializes it to be a dynamically allocated block of memory of the desired size for your array.